# Why can't function name be the same as return name type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Not sure what I am missing, but why wont this compile?

```
class Game
{
};

class Actor
{
   Game* mGame;
   Game* Game() { return mGame; }
};

int main()
{
  Actor a();

  return 0;
}
```

g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o test

```
main.cpp:8:10: error: declaration of ‘Game* Actor::Game()’ changes meaning of ‘Game’ [-fpermissive]
    8 |    Game* Game() { return mGame; }
      |          ^~~~
main.cpp:1:7: note: ‘Game’ declared here as ‘class Game’
    1 | class Game
      |
```

Obviously, if I change the function to GetGame, no problems.  Just wondering why - what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It won't compile because you are using the same name for two different purposes. I'm not sure why you are surprised.

Comment: This is a good question, and the answer is not obvious (not to me anyway). Note two things (i) `Actor a();`is a function prototype, not a declaration of an object of type `Actor`. (ii) MSVC compiles code like this. Note that g++ is correct not to compile, although I can't recall exactly why. Tag this as "language lawyer" too?

Comment: You might start function names with lower case (`Game* game();`). That's the more common convention anyway, e. g. all standard libraries follow this (well, but they don't do camel casing at all...). In 15 years of coding I've seen far more often lower camel case (`getGame`) than upper CC, both in libraries used as well as in companies coding conventions. Only Microsoft dominated domains (see WinAPI) seem to favour UCC...

Comment: @Aconcagua: I wonder if this is why MSVC relaxes the "constraint" (can't think of a better term) and compiles code such as the above?

Comment: Clang 10.0 is compile without a warning https://godbolt.org/z/dXavFm

Comment: Note, too, that (i) in @Bathsheba 's comment is not the cause for compilation failure, though. It's legal to declare functions inside other functions (but not to define them – apart from in form of a lambda).

Comment: Note that the issue is not so much that the member function has the same name as a class defined earlier, but that the name `Game` is used to refer to two different entities within the same scope. It's a subtle difference, but it's an important one. Ie. this would compile : `class Game{}; typedef Game GameAlias; class Actor {GameAlias* mGame; GameAlias* Game() {return mGame;}};`

Comment: (cont.) Or without the `typedef` for that matter : `class Game{}; class Actor {class Game* mGame; class Game* Game() {return mGame;}};` or `class Game{}; class Actor {::Game* mGame; ::Game* Game() {return mGame;}};`. Whatever makes the name different within the `Actor` scope.

Comment: Unrelated: `Actor a();` is a function declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code the way it currently is, I tested it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) using various compilers...

Here are the results of 3 different compilers, their generated assembly, and possible errors or warnings. All compiler options are set to `-std=c++17 -O3`.

---

**x86-64 clang(trunk)**

**asm**

```
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

**Warnings-Errors**

> ```
> warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function
> declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
> ```

where `a();` is highlighted as the warning in question

---

**x86-64 gcc (trunk)**

Fails to compile!

**Warnings-Errors**

> ```
> error: declaration of 'Game*' Actor::Game()' changes meaning of
> 'Game' [-fpermissive]
> ```

where `Game()` is highlighted as the error in question

---

**x64 msvc v19.24**

**asm**

```
main    PROC
        xor     eax, eax
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

**Warnings-Errors**

> ```
> warning C4930: 'Actor a(void)': prototyped function not called
> (was a variable definition intended?)
> ```

where `Actor a();` is highlighted as the warning in question

---

---

These are the results based on your current code. Now let's look at these 3 same examples but modifying just one little piece of your code...

I'm going to change `Actor a();` in your `main` function to `Actor a{};` instead and let's look at the differences...

---

---

**x86-64 clang(trunk)**

**asm**

```
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

**Warnings-Errors**

None!

---

**x86-64 gcc (trunk)**

Fails to compile!

**Warnings-Errors**

> ```
> error: declaration of 'Game*' Actor::Game()' changes meaning of
> 'Game' [-fpermissive]
> ```

where `Game()` is highlighted as the error in question.

---

**x64 msvc v19.24**

**asm**

```
a$ = 0
main    PROC
$LN3:
        push    rdi
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rax, QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        mov     rdi, rax
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     ecx, 8
        rep stosb
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rdi
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

**Warnings-Errors**

None!

---

---

**Assessment**

If you compare the 3 you will see that both `Clang` and `MSVC` will compile in both situations, however, they will both give a warning for the first case and will compile without error for the second. `GCC`, on the other hand, fails to compile in both cases and generates the same exact warning or compiler error.

In the first case which is your original source, `Clang` and `MSVC` are able to determine that you meant to call the constructor of said class `Actor` but generates a warning message where `GCC` fails to compile it all together while using the `()` operator. `GCC` can not determine if you meant to call `Actor::Game()` or `Game::Game()`.

We can also reason that both `Clang` and `MSVC` are pointing their warnings from the first case at `a()` while `GCC` is pointing its error at `Game()` in both cases.

To inspect what is going on even more, in the first case, both `Clang` and `MSVC` are generating almost identical assembly. In the second case, `Clang` is still generating the same assembly, but `MSVC`footprint tells a completely different story!

What I can say from my current knowledge without doing any more research, based on the comparisons between

```
Actor a();
```

and

```
Actor a{};
```

and the behavior that I'm seeing from the generated warnings, errors, and assembly code is this...

I believe that it might be `Implementation Defined` across the different compilers.

I can not say if this is `UB` or not, but I would probably suspect that it could be in some cases in which you can see from the generated assembly, warnings, and errors above...

If you are using the `()` operator for the class's constructor, then there is at least some ambiguity within all three compilers. `GCC` doesn't even compile and generates an error. `Clang` and `MSVC` both compile where `Clang` gives the warning that the empty parenthesis is interpreted as a function declaration and `MSVC` gives the warning that the prototyped function was not called.

Yet when we switch to the `{}` operator or initializer list... `Clang` generates the same assembly that it did before but no longer generates a warning. `MSVC` gives a thorough set of `instructions` to where it appears that both classes are being constructed and generates no warning. `GCC` craps out in both situations and says, "I give up on your intentions" here's my error message always pointing at `Game()`!

---

---

**Conclusion**

So to answer your question:

> Why can't function name be the same as return name type?

Depending on the context of use and the compiler that is being used it could be the same, and for other compilers, they may or will reject it.

So who's to say which compiler's interpretation is accurate and correct... I don't have a copy of the `standard` so I can not dive any further into the `language-lawyer` part of this, but I can generalize what is happening and why it is happening as I have just demonstrated.

I hope that this reasoning might help you within the naming conventions and how the compilers try to interpret such names and symbols while trying to turn them into objects.

So there may be some ambiguity in some contexts and no ambiguity in others. This leads me to believe this is implementation-defined across compilers since `AFAIK` the standard doesn't require a specific notation of `name-reuse` and that this could lead to `UB`! Therefore, this would not be good practice and definitely a code smell!

And all of this is agnostic of the hardware architecture too!

Comment: It seems from other answers that this is well-defined, and if so, compilers that do wrong things should have bugs filed against them.

Answer (score 3):

Since the language lawyer tag has been added, and there appears to be some confusion as to whether this is defined by the standard or not, here's what the standard has to say to complement the existing answers.

In *[basic.scope.hiding]* :

> If a class name (11.2) or enumeration name (9.6) and a variable, data member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same declarative region (in any order) with the same name (excluding declarations made visible via *using-directives* (6.4.1)), the class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is visible.

Furthermore, in *[class.name]* we find :

> If a class name is declared in a scope where a variable, function, or enumerator of the same name is also declared, then when both declarations are in scope, the class can be referred to only using an *elaborated-type-specifier* (6.4.4). *[Example:*

```
struct stat {
  // ...
};

stat gstat;                // use plain stat to define variable

int stat(struct stat*);    // redeclare stat as function

void f() {
  struct stat* ps;         // struct prefix needed to name struct stat
  stat(ps);                // call stat()
}
```

> *— end example]*

So, in the scope of `f`, `stat` refers to the function of that name, whereas `struct stat` (elaborated type specifier) refers to the class.

Or in the example from the OP, in the scope of `Actor`, `Game` refers to the (member) function of that name, whereas `class Game` (elaborated type specifier) refers to the class.

Note that alternatively, `::Game` can be used to refer to the class.

Finally, a bit further down in *[class.name]*, there's a relevant quote about writing such code :

> 4 *[Note:* The declaration of a class name takes effect immediately after the *identifier* is seen in the class definition or *elaborated-type-specifier*. For example, `class A * A;` first specifies `A` to be the name of a class and then redefines it as the name of a pointer to an object of that class. This means that the elaborated form `class A` must be used to refer to the class. Such artistry with names can be confusing and is best avoided. *— end note]*

So not only does the standard fully cover this scenario - it also recommends against writing such confusing code.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
class Game
{
};

class Actor
{
   Game* mGame;
   Game* Game() { return mGame; }
   void test() { auto g = Game(); /*constructing game or calling fn and saving ptr result?*/ }
};
```

Sure, this can be resolved using `::Game()` vs `this->Game()`, but the default is ambiguous because the standard doesn't state which to prefer in the case of symbol-name reuse. Therefore, it will not compile due to ambiguity.

Comment: This is true at least from the perspective of `GCC`, but for `Clang` and `MSVC` you'll get different results! Also, if the OP changes `Actor a()` to `Actor a{}` in `main()`, `GCC` still behaves exactly the same, `Clang` generates the same assembly but no longer provides a warning, and `MSVC` produces completely different assembly without any warnings. So there may be some ambiguity in some contexts and no ambiguity in others. This leads me to believe this is `implementation-defined` and could lead to `UB`.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I saw your answer. "standard doesn't state which to prefer in the case of symbol-name reuse" means it's not defined -- different compilers may have different implementations.

Comment: That's why I liked your answer for I thought it was very useful for the OP. I provided my own because I feel that your answer doesn't show the full picture when you are not comparing different compilers...